# In 64-bit ASM. Is there a nice way of NOTing only the bottom 32-bits of a register

Tags: x86, assembly

Assuming we have some value in RAX. We wish to NOT the lower 32-bits of RAX, and leave the upper 32 bits unchanged. Is there a nice way of doing this?

A command like:

```
not eax
```

Unfortunately zero extends.

I can do it as follows:

```
mov rbx,rax
not ebx ; or not rbx
and rax, 0xffffffff00000000
or rax, rbx
```

but it feels like there should be a nicer way.

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I think you want a 64 bit `0xffffffff00000000` in that and, rather than the 32 bit value you've currently got (which results in bits 16-31 remaining the same and everything else being zeroed).

Comment: I typed without thinking properly. Edited, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could XOR it with `0x00000000ffffffff`, that would flip the bottom 32 bits.

Comment: @LarsViklund Thanks for the correction. Somehow, I looked at that and went "0000ffff, that's 32 bits." And it is, but I wanted 64 bits, the bottom 32 being ones.

Comment: @Vatine, thanks I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: One issue is that XOR only takes a 32 bit signed immediate, so you'd need  to XOR with a 64 bit value in memory, or use a MOV with a 64 bit immediate and then use XOR.

Comment: @rcgldr you can make that a 32bit mov, saves some space. You can even make it `or r32, -1` for minimum space but it has a fake dependency.

Comment: @rcgldr or use `MOVZX`.

Comment: @8bittree: Are you talking about an imm32 operand being sign extended?  Otherwise no, that's not how XOR works.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, I was thinking in NAND, instead of XOR. Vatine's answer is correct now that I've thought about it a bit more.

Comment: @rwong - I looked at Intel instruction reference, and there is a MOVSXD, but I don't see a MOVZXD.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Based on the Intel instruction pdf file, in the case of something like XOR RAX, imm32, it's prefixed with REG.W, and imm32 will be sign extended.

Comment: @rcgldr: the comment I was replying to was deleted.  It had a logic error about what `xor` would do.  Yes, imm32 operands are sign extended in instructions with a 64bit operand size.

Comment: @rwong: you *could* get `0x00000000ffffffff` into a register with `movsx eax, byte [minus_one]`.  `movsx` and `movzx` are not available in immediate-operand form.  So I'd suggest `mov eax, -1` would be the fastest way.  (Or harold's `or eax, -1` is shorter, and just as fast if you have a dead reg (as far as dependency-chains).)